# Finding i! closed form expression

Tags: factorial

OK. I've seen threads about how to calculate $i!$, so I looked it up and it is approximately $0.49801566811835604271369111746219809195296296758765009289 - 0.15494982830181068512495513048388660519587965207932493026 i$.

The magnitude of $i!$ (I had to do some digging for this one) turns out to be $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\sinh\pi}}$.

But my question is, what are the closed-form expressions for those real and imaginary parts of $i!$? How would you write the $0.498015668...$ and $0.154949828...$ *in terms of known mathematical constants? Is there even a way to do this?*

**I am using the Gamma function to generalize the factorial. So $i!=\Gamma\left(1+i\right)$.**

Comment: To be perfectly clear, the factorial is traditionally defined only for natural numbers in which case $i!$ is not defined.  Are you asking instead about $\Gamma(i+1)$, where $\Gamma(z)=\int\limits_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)?

Comment: $\Gamma(i+1)=i\Gamma(i)$, and the decimal expansions of the real and imaginary parts of $\Gamma(i)$ are https://oeis.org/A212877 and https://oeis.org/A212878 respectively.  No, it does not appear that there are any nice closed forms.